# A GET request from a GAS web app as if it were from a user autenticated browser (under GSuite)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Is it possible to write under Google Apps Script a web app who performs a GET by UrlFetchApp.fetch(...) as if it were a request coming from a browser with a GSuite user correctly logged in?
What I need is to send a GET request from my app to another GAS web app accessible only by my domain's users (GSuite).
The main reason I need this is that the second app works on a Google Sheet visible and writable only by my staff, meanwhile the initial GET sent by the first app must be deliverable by everyone, also anonymously.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not just open up your second web app to public access?

Comment: @Roberto Tognelli Read [Tanaike's GAS Web App Guide](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script). It covers everything you need to know to set up a user authenticated GAS Web App.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a GET request from one Apps Script Web App to another Apps Script Web App within the same domain, and restrict access within the domain.

A Web App can be published with a "Who has access to the app:" setting of:

> Anyone within {Your Domain Name Here}

That will restrict access to anyone in your domain.

[image: Who has access to Web App]